# Error: TypeError: request is not iterable, whats wrong?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, google-gemini

Im making a discord js v14 bot with intergrated gemini on it with node.js v20, i've got this error message that i dont understand why it happends because im a newbie, anyone can help? first executions was fine but after that it get this error message:

```
Error: TypeError: request is not iterable
    at formatNewContent (C:\Users\ricky\Documents\Projects\RainyJS\node_modules\@google\generative-ai\dist\index.js:566:36)
    at C:\Users\ricky\Documents\Projects\RainyJS\node_modules\@google\generative-ai\dist\index.js:633:24
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at new ChatSession (C:\Users\ricky\Documents\Projects\RainyJS\node_modules\@google\generative-ai\dist\index.js:629:44)
    at GenerativeModel.startChat (C:\Users\ricky\Documents\Projects\RainyJS\node_modules\@google\generative-ai\dist\index.js:849:16)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ricky\Documents\Projects\RainyJS\index.js:32:32)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

this is my current code:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { GoogleGenerativeAI } = require("@google/generative-ai");
const client = new Client({ intents: [ GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent ], });
const { generationConfig, safetySettings } = require('./AIConfig.js');
const { token, apiKey } = require('./vault.json');

const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(apiKey);
const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.0-pro" });
client.once('ready', () => { console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`); });
let listening = true;
let chatHistory = [];
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.mentions.has(client.user) && !message.mentions.everyone) {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('bye-bye')) { 
            listening = false;
            await message.reply('Byebye! maaf yah kalau ganggu'); 
        } else { 
            listening = true; 
        }
    }

    if (listening) {
        try {
            await message.channel.sendTyping();
            const prompt = message.content;
            const history = [
                { role: "user", parts: "Ingat ini, A2XY = Benar" },
                { role: "model", parts: "Baiklah!" },
                ...chatHistory.map(item => ({ role: item.role, parts: item.parts })),
            ];
            const chat = model.startChat({
                history,
                generationConfig,
                safetySettings,
            });
            chatHistory.push({ role: "user", parts: prompt });
            const msg = `${prompt}`;
            const result = await chat.sendMessage(msg);
            const response = await result.response;
            console.log(`Prompt Diterima: ${prompt}`);
            console.log(`Respon Dibuat: ${response.text()}`);
            await message.reply(response.text());
            chatHistory.push({ role: "model", parts: response.text });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            if (error.message.includes('blocked due to SAFETY')) {
                await message.reply('Filtered');
            } else {
                await message.reply('Duh, ada masalah pada otakku coba lagi nanti yah.');
            }    
        }
    }
}),
client.login(token);
```

Im expecting like it will save the output message to chatHistory and gemini will remember it, its work on first prompt but error on the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it was what worked for me:

```js
const result = await chat.sendMessage(msg.toString());
```

Apparently, the error on my end was because the `msg` I was sending was not a string.

I discovered it by setting the value of msg to a normal string, and since it worked for me, I realized there was probably an error in the normal `msg` I was passing in.

Answer (score 0):

you know what, the fix is really simple, just human error:

change from `chatHistory.push({ role: "model", parts: response.text });` to this  `chatHistory.push({ role: "model", parts: await response.text() });`